# How to iterate out data with ngFor or other with objects containing arrays?

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array of objects which look something like this:

```
[
    {
    id: 1,
    settings: "[{object},{object}]", <-- stringifiedJSON
    stats: "[{object}, {object}]" <-- stringifiedJSON
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    settings: "[{object},{object}]", <-- stringifiedJSON
    stats: "[{object}, {object}]" <-- stringifiedJSON
    },
]
```

In the request, I use the map method on the array and parse the strings like so:

```
settings = [];
stats = [];

getAllArchives(){
    this.archiveService.getArchives()
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response) {
          this.archives = response.data;
          this.stats = this.archives.map(archive => JSON.parse(archive.stats));
          this.settings = this.archives.map(archive => JSON.parse(archive.game_settings));
          console.log(this.stats);<-this logs the two stats arrays correctly
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

I am trying to then display them in the browser using:

```
*ngFor="let archive of archives" - there are currently 2 objects in this array
```

Once the archives array is iterating, if I try to iterate out stat of stats, I find that stats are iterated out to the length of archives and shows all the stats in one section, not the array of stats for that archive id. Settings are the same and so on.

I understand why this is happening, but have not previously encountered a time when I have had to iterate out arrays within arrays which are unique to a particular object.

I have looked about for a precedent, but have not found a similar problem yet.

I am basically looking to iterate out something like this in the end, but can't manage it.

[1]setting, [1]stats

[2]setting, [2]stats

what I get at the minute is:

[1]setting, [2]setting, [1]stats, [2]stats

[1]setting, [2]setting, [1]stats, [2]stats

Is there a better way to set the data before it is displayed in the component? Can I index the ngfor loop effectively to display the data correctly? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use mapping to iterate over `archives` array and convert `stringified JSONs` to proper `JSON objects`.

```
this.archives.map(x => {
    x.settings = JSON.parse(x.settings);
    x.stats = JSON.parse(x.stats);
});
```

Then you can use `*ngFor` on `settings` and `stats` also. Sample `html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let archive of archives">
    <p>{{archive.id}}</p>
    <div *ngFor="let setting of archive.settings">
        <p>{{setting.<property>}}</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let stats of archive.stats">
        <p>{{stats.<property>}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cpqhk)